# How to get the value of data-* attribute in knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm new to knockout js and I have came across an issue where in the following lines of code

```
<input type="checkbox" value="true"  data-bind =" attr: { id: 'chk' + action.id, value: id, 'data-id': action.id }, checked: $root.checked"  name="checkbox" class="checkbox">
```

I have added `data-id` and I wanna get that value in the knockout view model. How can I do that with knockout js

Comment: Can you please post your view model?  Is `action.id` an `observable`?

Answer (score 0):

`var id = action.id();`
Check this [http://jsfiddle.net/yaroslavya/Xd6Ej/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/yaroslavya/Xd6Ej/).
By clicking different save buttons you get different action.id value. This is the value that is connected to data-id attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what I really want is mentioned in the following jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/txMLg/

When the saveAction function clicked, I want to get the value of data-id

Comment: It seems you do not have the view model. Can you please update the jsfiddle to use the viewmodel you have?

Comment: Its not pure Knockout, its with Durandal JS, so there's no typical view model we have in knockout is here. Anyway this is the updated version of the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/txMLg/1/

In this one, I have attached it to the id itself in the viewmodel

Comment: You see, the example is broken as there`s no dc defined. So when building jsfiddle you have to make sure it provides all the things required to make example work. I will use knockout only and give you the link, one moment.